# Silverlight localization - how to override windows culture

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, localization

I got english windows version and currently can't debug this but I am localizing application for two languages russsian and english.

From what I understand following code should be enough in App constructor:

```
            if (Language == Language.Russian) {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = RUSSIAN_CULTURE;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = RUSSIAN_CULTURE;
            }
            else {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ENGLISH_CULTURE;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ENGLISH_CULTURE;
            }
```

Cultures objects are correct cultures (ru-RU , en-US).

However when application is ran on Russian windows that if is ignored, and only russian strings are used.

Notice that language change works perfectly correct on my machine (en windows)

Comment: Sometimes it´s not enough to set the langauge only on the current Thread, cause some controls (aka. DataGrid) doens´t respect this value. You should also set the Language property of UserControls like so this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

Comment: If some part of application was rus, other eng. it could be the issue. But I believe controls as simple as TextBlock respect should respect Thread.CultureInfo? there is no example of control that shows anything in english, when app is ran on ru windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added new en specific culture resource and it has solved the problem.
However now I got english resources duplicated - they are default & same go into en-US specific resource. I believe there must be a way to remove such duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I read this in "CLR via C#" book by Jeff Richter:

(about CurrentUICulture)

> By default, when you create a thread, this thread property is set to a
>   CulterInfo object, which identifies the language of the Windows
>   version the application is running on using Win32
>   GetUserDefaultUILanguage function. If you are running a Multilingual
>   User Interface (MUI) version of windows, you can set this via the
>   "Regional and Language Options" Control Panel settings. On a non-MUI
>   version of Windows, the language is determined by the localised
>   version of the OS installed (or the installed language pack) and the
>   language is not changeable.

Comment: ive read CLR via C# but I dont think this is related to my problem or silverlight localization..

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my silverlight view constructor, not in the App constructor:

```
    //seting language for currency and datetime
    string sDefaultLocalization = "ru-RU";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(sDefaultLocalization);
    this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Comment: Language is more related "To properly display Chinese, Japanese, and Korean text, Silverlight needs to know which language it is displaying, because the same Unicode characters are displayed differently depending on language." I believe. Other than that I got same code setting Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in my question that should be working..